# ¿Cómo llevar un contador de modificaciones al registro en MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Tengo un problema, tengo una tabla en ACCESS con varios campos y necesito, de alguna manera, hacer que al modificar cualquiera de esos campos altere otro campo. A modo de ejemplo:

Tenemos una tabla llamada `clientes` y tengo el campo `fecha`, `nombre`, `numero de cliente`, `dni`, `dirección`, `edad`, etc. Y adicionalmente un campo que lo llamare `CAMBIO`, este campo `CAMBIO` por defecto va a venir en 0.

Lo que necesito es que al realizar cualquier cambio en los otros campos (`fecha`, `nombre`, `numero de cliente`, `dni`, `dirección`, `edad`, etc) el campo `CAMBIO` pase de 0 a 1.

Puede ser de A a B o lo que fuese, pero que de manera automática al cambiar o modificar los valores del cualquier campo este cambie también.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! EDITO: access no tiene triggers, pero tiene algo que se llama macros de datos. investiga sobre eso (es algo asi como un trigger)

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por el dato, investigare un poco al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que buscas, puedes crear una macro de evento *Antes del cambio*, que es una especie de *trigger* que se va a lanzar antes de realizar un *update* a la tabla. En este, puedes manipular el valor del campo `cambio`, para ir incrementándolo de manera automática.

Para hacerlo, haz doble clic en la tabla `clientes`, selecciona la pestaña *"Tabla"*, y luego haz clic en el botón *"Antes del Cambio"* de la sección *"Eventos anteriores"*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí, agrega una nueva acción de tipo *"Establecer Campo"*, en nombre coloca `CAMBIO` y en valor `= [CAMBIO] + 1`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Guarda y cierra los cambios al evento.

La próxima vez que se modifique un registro, el campo CAMBIO va a incrementar de manera automática.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.